# sqoop export performance Issues

Tags: performance, hadoop, export, sqoop, netezza

I am facing performance issues in exporting data from Hive to Netezza via sqoop export.

Is there any way to improve the performance of sqoop?

Here are the details:

```
columns present in the table(source and destination) : 282
format of file : text
no of splits: 99
data to be exported : 1000 MB
```

Comment: can you add your sample `sqoop` command?

Comment: I would ask you to break the process into multiple threads , parallel loads that way you can improve the transfer speed

Comment: Here is the sample sqoop command used : sqoop export -Dmapreduce.job.queuename=QUEUENAME  --connect jdbc:netezza://SERVER_STRING/DB_NAME --username USER --password-file /PATH --table TABLE_NAME --batch --columns "LIST OF 282 COLOUMNS " --export-dir /DIR_PATH --input-fields-terminated-by '\001' --lines-terminated-by '\n'  --input-null-string "\\\N" --input-null-non-string "\\\N" -m 100

Answer (score 1):

Use -batch in the sqoop export command. 
Also

To further improve the data load you can use --direct. 
Limitation: Binary and Large Object types are not supported in this mode.

Answer (score 0):

What is your cluster size and how many max slots you can allocate to your Sqoop job ? Accordingly give the -m . that will increase the overall processing time. But please make sure that the sqoop export is not the atomic process, so create a staging table and then use the staging table to export the data else there may be a chance of inconsistent data.